# WPF mvvm messenger destructor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have MainWindow thath holds `<ContentControl ... Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}"` in MainViewModel I am switching between two View `FirstView`,`SecondView`. `FirstView` contains usercontrol `ContentFirstView` that implementing async data sending to `ContentSecondViewModel`. Data send's with time delay 1000ms. The main question is why when i am clicking on 1,2,1,2,1,2 buttons the speed of updating label `Count` in `ContentSecondView` greatly increasing? I think that `ContentSecondViewModel` do not disposing and every time when i am clicking on button 2, it creates new object of Messenger.Register ...

MainModel.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Button Content="1" Command="{Binding FirstCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="2" Command="{Binding SecondCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
</Grid>
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    /// 

    public RelayCommand FirstCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => SwitchFirst());
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand SecondCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(()=>SwitchSecond());
        }
    }

    public static readonly FirstViewModel firstViewModel = new FirstViewModel();
    public static readonly SecondViewModel secondViewModel = new SecondViewModel();

    ViewModelBase currentViewModel;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return currentViewModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (currentViewModel == value)
                return;
            currentViewModel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
        }
    }
    public void SwitchFirst()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel.firstViewModel;
    }
    public void SwitchSecond()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel.secondViewModel;
    }
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        CurrentViewModel = MainViewModel.secondViewModel;
        ////if (IsInDesignMode)
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        ////}
        ////else
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs "for real"
        ////}
    }
}
```

SecondView.xaml:

```
  <Grid>
    <views:ContentSecondView></views:ContentSecondView>
</Grid>
```

FirstView.xaml:

```
    <Grid>
    <views:ContentFirstView></views:ContentFirstView>
</Grid>
```

ContentFirstView.xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Label>View That sending data</Label>
</Grid>
```

ContentSecondView.xaml:

```
    <Grid>
    <Label>View That sending data</Label>
</Grid>
```

ContentFirstViewModel.cs:

```
public class ContentFirstViewModel
{
    public RelayCommand SendMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => Send());
        }
    }
    public void Send()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Send<MessageCommuniactor>(new MessageCommuniactor {State=1 });
    }
      public void Increase()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Messenger.Default.Send<MessageCommuniactor>(new MessageCommuniactor { State = 1 });
        }

    }
      public ContentFirstViewModel()
    {
        Action A = new Action(Increase);
        IAsyncResult result = A.BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

ContentSecondViewModel.cs:

```
public class ContentSecondViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    private int count;

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this.count;
        }

        set
        {
            this.count = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Count");
        }
    }

    public ContentSecondViewModel()
    {
        Messenger.Default.Register<MessageCommuniactor>(this, (key) => 
        { 
            Count += key.State; 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you using to bind the VM to the View?  If MEF, you can set the PartCreationPolicy to Shared to ensure the VM is a singleton.  If not, well, make sure that every time the View is swapped out, it's not creating a new VM to bind with.

Comment: To bind VM to the View I am using something like this.            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ContentFirstViewModel}">
                <views:ContentFirstView />
            </DataTemplate>

Comment: In case you haven't got this worked out yet, your datatemplate ensures that a new view is created every time a ContentFirstViewModel is present.  Instead, go with a singleton approach where a singleton view is injected when needed.  You can use Prism's regionmanager or simple binding for that.

Comment: outbred you right! When i used IOC Container problem with destructor disappeared. Write answer i will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your DataTemplate ensures that a new view is created every time a ContentFirstViewModel is present. Instead, go with a singleton approach where a singleton view is injected when needed. You can use Prism's regionmanager or simple binding for that.